# Firebase event in different class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm building simple Android app to learn Java coding. Because app is pretty good I want to publish it on Google Play and track what users do inside of it. But I stuck on Firebase event integration. I have MainActivity.java where I call with this:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Now I have buttons which I want to track in different class, Buttons.java

```
        Play.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (MusicPlayer.playerStatus) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    MainActivity.getStartOrStopBtn().setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                } else if (LoadingAnimation.hasEnded()) {
                    try {
                        MusicList.next(0, mainListLocation, mainRadioName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here I must include code below but I can not figure out how to:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, 
bundle);
```

Can someone explain me on beginner level how to include this Firebase event tracking on that specific button which is in different class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the instance again in the second class:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```